# Element "flickers" and Moves on fadeOut/fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm using the following code to `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` content divs on a page ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SbKQ3/1/))...

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="indexNav" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="aboutNav" href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="indexContent">
  This is the main page content.
</div>

<div id="aboutContent">
  This is the about page content.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #7d5900;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 36, 125, 0.5);
}

#aboutContent {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#indexNav').click(function() {
  $('#aboutContent').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#indexContent').fadeIn('fast');
  return false;
});

$('#aboutNav').click(function() {
  $('#indexContent').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#aboutContent').fadeIn('fast');
  return false;
});
```

As demonstrated in [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbKQ3/1/) (at least in Firefox 9.0.1 and IE 9 on Windows 7), when clicking back and forth between the links to show/hide the elements in question, there is a bit of a page-wide flicker as the elements animate.  Basically, the `div` moves far down the page, which causes a scrollbar to appear and push the `div` a little to the left, then it returns to normal when the animation finishes.

Not being an expert in CSS by any means, I've just been sort of tinkering with this to try to achieve a simple fade-out/fade-in effect (using jQuery, naturally).  So I'm wondering if there's a more correct way to do this or if I'm making some kind of fundamental mistake in my design that's just not known to me.

Any ideas on what might be causing this flicker and how to correct it?

Comment: why do you have page links in the hrefs if you're loading other hidden divs on the page? ...just wondering

Comment: @hanzolo: Oh, I forgot to remove those for the example.  They're in place because I have plans for a more graceful degradation of the site in the event that JavaScript isn't enabled.  But they're not relevant to the context of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#indexNav').click(function() {
    $('#aboutContent').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('#indexContent').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    return false;
});

$('#aboutNav').click(function() {
    $('#indexContent').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('#aboutContent').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  I need to use the callback to wait for the animation to properly finish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This occurs because your elements are displayed relatively.  That means that when both are present on the screen, they move each other around.  When you do a cross-fade, which is essentially what you are doing, they will both be on the screen for a time.  You need to absolutely position the elements to occupy the same space.

```
#aboutContent, #indexContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2TDj5/

You can put the elements in a wrapper div, which will allow you to position them relative to the page, but absolute with regard to each other.  Just make sure that you explicitly set the wrapper to `display: relative`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2TDj5/1/

Comment: Interesting.  I'll admit, I've been averse to using absolute positioning for years, but for this simple little site it may make my life a bit easier.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with absolute positioning.  But you need to use it correctly.  Absolutely positioning elements relative to the body in a lot of cases is not very robust on different screens. (Such as my quick example).  But, as I state in the rest of my answer, as long as you absolute position within a wrapper, it doesn't limit the flexibility of your page.

Comment: Indeed, the key has always been "to use it correctly" (which I apparently wasn't even doing with the fade functions in this case).  And I don't have a lot of experience with UI development, so helpful tips like yours go a long way for me to use the tools correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: thats all i was missing..tried thousands of examples but nothing worked out...Thanks for explaining the whole concept...

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple

```
.delay( 1 ).fadeIn(...)
```

should help