# div “flickers” and Moves on fadeOut/fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the same problem that is described here: [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991652/element-flickers-and-moves-on-fadeout-fadein) (fiddle: [original fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SbKQ3/1/)) but I dont understand JS yet, I am learning as I code, so when my html code is little bit different as it is now, I dont know, how to apply the solution onto it. Could You help me please with that? When I see, how it should look, I can learn it then.

My code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: -50%;">
        <div id="101" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="102" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="103" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="104" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="105" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="106" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="107" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="108" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="109" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="110" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="111" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="112" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
        <div id="113" style="display:none;"><!-- Content here --></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#1").on('click', function() {
    $("#101").fadeToggle();
    $("#102,#103,#104,#105,#106,#107,#108,#109,#110,#111,#112,#113").fadeOut();
    });

    $("#2").on('click', function() {
    $("#102").fadeToggle();
    $("#101,#103,#104,#105,#106,#107,#108,#109,#110,#111,#112,#113").fadeOut();
    });

    // and so on, until #13 
</script>
```

Solution:

```
$('#indexNav').click(function() {
$('#aboutContent').fadeOut('fast',function(){
    $('#indexContent').fadeIn('fast');
});
return false;
});
$('#aboutNav').click(function() {
$('#indexContent').fadeOut('fast',function(){
    $('#aboutContent').fadeIn('fast');
});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, as you put the solution to your question?

Comment: I found the same problem (flickering when changing divs with fade) but I cant implement the solution to my code, because I dont know how, because my code is little different than the original one. I dont understant JS at all, so I realy dont know how to fix my code, acording the original one... So I am asking for help. If someone could show me, how my code should looks like, when fixed. I can learn from that a lot...

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that? I used `promises` to `fadeToggle` only when all elements were hidden, which prevented the flickering effect.

```js
$(function() { // equivalent to onDomReady
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    // get this element's id
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // find the corresponding div ID, which seems to be 100 greater than original ID
    $.when($('#1' + id).siblings().fadeOut()).done(function() {
        $('#1' + id).fadeToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div div div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="01">01</button>
<button id="02">02</button>
<button id="03">03</button>
<button id="04">04</button>
<button id="05">05</button>
<button id="06">06</button>
<button id="07">07</button>
<button id="08">08</button>
<button id="09">09</button>
<button id="10">10</button>
<button id="11">11</button>
<button id="12">12</button>
<button id="13">13</button>

<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
  <div style="position: relative; left: -50%;">
    <div id="101" style="display: none;">101</div>
    <div id="102" style="display: none;">102</div>
    <div id="103" style="display: none;">103</div>
    <div id="104" style="display: none;">104</div>
    <div id="105" style="display: none;">105</div>
    <div id="106" style="display: none;">106</div>
    <div id="107" style="display: none;">107</div>
    <div id="108" style="display: none;">108</div>
    <div id="109" style="display: none;">109</div>
    <div id="110" style="display: none;">110</div>
    <div id="111" style="display: none;">111</div>
    <div id="112" style="display: none;">112</div>
    <div id="113" style="display: none;">113</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfect, Thank You very much. I would never found solution like this by myself. You are my hero. Very clean solution. Anyone could learn from You! I will try to understand the code to know, why there is written this and that and definitely will learn from it. Thank You again.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, thats a lot of code to review. I'm not positive this is going to solve your problem. You don't have any hover events on this, so I assume flicker may be CSS related.

```js
// better selector - you don't have markup for #1, #2, #3, etc.
// can you rework this to be $('.container div') or something based on real markup
$('div').on('click', function() {

  // get this element's id
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  // find the corresponding div ID, which seems to be 100 greater than original ID
  $('#1'+id).fadeToggle()
      // find all siblings and hide them
      .siblings().fadeOut();

});
```

I've added a snippet so you can test it.

```js
$(function() { // equivalent to onDomReady
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    // get this element's id
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // find the corresponding div ID, which seems to be 100 greater than original ID
    $('#1' + id).fadeToggle()
      // find all siblings and hide them
      .siblings().fadeOut();

  });
});
```

```css
div div div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="01">01</button>
<button id="02">02</button>
<button id="03">03</button>
<button id="04">04</button>
<button id="05">05</button>
<button id="06">06</button>
<button id="07">07</button>
<button id="08">08</button>
<button id="09">09</button>
<button id="10">10</button>
<button id="11">11</button>
<button id="12">12</button>
<button id="13">13</button>

<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
  <div style="position: relative; left: -50%;">
    <div id="101" style="display: none;">101</div>
    <div id="102" style="display: none;">102</div>
    <div id="103" style="display: none;">103</div>
    <div id="104" style="display: none;">104</div>
    <div id="105" style="display: none;">105</div>
    <div id="106" style="display: none;">106</div>
    <div id="107" style="display: none;">107</div>
    <div id="108" style="display: none;">108</div>
    <div id="109" style="display: none;">109</div>
    <div id="110" style="display: none;">110</div>
    <div id="111" style="display: none;">111</div>
    <div id="112" style="display: none;">112</div>
    <div id="113" style="display: none;">113</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**
What you're suffering from is the moment of time when both divs (one fading out, and one fading in) are being toggled. You'll need to position those divs absolutely to get around this. Then they're overlapping each other and you don't need to worry about the flicker. That can have big impacts on layout. Then you get into calculating heights of those child divs and all sorts of stuff:
https://jsfiddle.net/SbKQ3/29/

Comment: That's the best way to do it. There may be some changes in the animations (adding callbacks), but the general idea is good.

Comment: Wow, thak You very much, it´s very impresive, but the snippet suffers from flickering too. See this fiddle for what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/SbKQ3/1/ Is there any way to avoid that?